# calculate remote fs root from master hostname

Tags: jenkins

I have two jenkins masters - call them "master1" and "master2" - and a remote node, call it "node1".  I want to keep the node configuration for "node1" the same in master1 and master2.  However - I would like to dynamically calculate the remote FS root property of node1 so that it is different depending on whether the jenkins slave process is started by master1 or master2.  So, in the node configuration, here:

```
Remote FS root = /home/jenkins/<????>
```

is there something I can enter for ???? that will result in a different absolute workspace path for slaves started on master1 vs master2?  (Note: the key is I want ???? to be the *same* on all masters; I want to avoid hard-coding in unique values like "master1" or "master2".)